# How to access website on client machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I created management information system for school in MVC 4 which is role based system and configured it on server though IIS. It works fine on single machine (server).Now i need to share that application on LAN network without internet. I have no idea about how to share this to client system.I read many of tutorial but that didn't help me anymore.Please help me i spent lot of time on this issue but got no solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell what you have tried already so we can help you.

Comment: i replace the localhost in url with ip address after getting ip address of server but it gives me message that web page is not available.

Comment: I think you need to "ping" Application server from client machine so you can check connectivity of Client and application server. For Ping Use Command Prompt and Type command "ping YourApplicationServerIP"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Check the IP address of system in which you hosted the application: eg: 10.0.1.12

2.Replace the localhost in URL  with the IP address.
ie `http://localhost/YourApplicationFolder`

`http://10.0.1.12/YourApplicationFolder`

3.Add an inbound rule in firewall, for port 80.

4.Now try to access your website from another system with `http://10.0.1.12/YourApplicationFolder`

**setting inbound rule.**

1.go to `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall`

2.select `Advanced settings` from left.

3.select `Inbound rule` from left.

4.Select `Add new rule` from right.

5.select `port` and Next.

6.Select `TCP` and `special port` specify 80. Next.

7.select `Allow the connection`.Next.

8.select `Domain`,`private`,`public`.Next

9.Add some `name` and `description`.

10.finish

you have to set this in server.

Comment: are you getting any error message when  you are accessing site from client system?

Comment: i got message that web  page is not available.

Comment: Have you added inbound rule? After doing the above steps just restart the iis.

Comment: i have no idea about inbound rule? will you please explain for me

Comment: i just turn off windows firewall only.

Comment: i have updated my answer with how to set inbound rule. Just try.

Comment: ok.thanks.i will check it and later on make an update. thanks once again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81392/discussion-between-waqas-and-spider-man).

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your Application folder in C:\inetpub\wwwroot
2. Open IIS and navigate to Your-PC > Sites > Default Web Site
3. Right click on your Application folder and convert to application
4. Now check your IP Address on other system browser if its not showing your IIS page then turn off your PC firewall and now you can access your application any system within LAN 
   Your URL will be Like http://192.168.1.1/AppFolder/

Thats it.

Comment: application is already in your mentioned folder and it is configured through iis.

Comment: turn off your Windows Firewall and then check